# Deriving the Runge-Kutta formula, repeated derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, runge-kutta-methods

This is a part of the derivation of a Runge-Kutta method. Consider the equation $$y' = f(t,y)$$

then $$y'' = f_t+fy\cdot y'$$

$$y'''=f_{tt}+f_{ty}f+(f_t+f_yf)f_y+f(f_{ty}+f_{tt}f)$$

where $f_t,f_y$ denote partial derivatives. Instead of talking about derivatives, we are considering differentials. Fine, but how do we arrive at this expression for $y'''$? Supposedly the chain rule is at work here, but I don't see it.

Edit : This is from the textbook, "Numerical analysis, Kincaid and Cheney". Specifically page 499.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks wrong... First insert the ODE in the second derivative
$$
y''=f_t+f_yf.
$$
Then apply the same total differentiation by $t$
\begin{align}
y'''&=(f_t+f_yf)_t+(f_t+f_yf)_yy'
\\
&=(f_{tt}+f_{yt}f+f_yf_t)+(f_{ty}+f_{yy}f+f_yf_y)y'
\\
&=f_{tt}+f_{yt}f+f_yf_t+(f_{ty}+f_{yy}f+f_yf_y)f
\end{align}
I do not see any $f_t^2$ or $ff_{tt}f$ terms occurring.
Collecting equal terms gives
$$
y'''=f_{tt}+2f_{yt}f+f_yf_t+f_{yy}f^2+f_yf_yf
$$
Note that the next derivative needs a more careful treatment if $y$ is not scalar, as terms like $f_yf_{yy}[f,f]$ and $f_{yy}[f_yf,f]$ are no longer the same.

Comment: Yes, one of the partial derivatives should have been $f_y$. I fixed the post

Comment: Still looks wrong, there is no way to get a term $f_{tt}f$. Also, please only correct genuine transcription errors. Put additional insights into additional sections of the question, clearly marking the chronological progression.